# The Wait Operation Timed Out - memory issues

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

This started happening on Tuesday so I wonder if it is a Windows Update Problem?
The Application is written in MVC and runs on a Windows 2012 R2 Server using SSMS Server 2014 and has run more or less OK since October last year.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that SQL Server was running out of memory. It was running on a 4Gb Windows 2012 R2 server and memory usage was 92%. I found that if I abandoned what was using the most memory (Redstor in this instance) SQL Server and the CRM were OK and complex (table with a join and sorted using Order By) would run in <1 second instead of reporting an error. The SQL Query:
Use CrmDatabase
select * from BranchOrders
join Branches on BranchOrders.BranchID = Branches.BranchID
where BranchOrders.BranchID = 100787
order by 1 desc

My suspicion was that a Redstor or Windows Update had caused changes in memory use which meant that there was insufficient memory for SQL Server.
When I abandoned Redstor it all started working again.

This was resolved by changing the server RAM from 4Gb to 8Gb and the problem went away. We now have another issue on the remote server but that is another story!